# Looking for this theme in Sublime text

Tags: themes, sublimetext3

Currently I'm taking a online video course, This theme really makes code easy to read, especially for javascript,

The images below are ".html" files , I believe the editor showed in the image is not sublime text. well, i'm the sublime text user, it will be really helpful if someone can please tell me the name of this kind of theme that is working in sublime text, thank you very much in advance.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Looks like "material dark"

Answer (score 0):

The theme is  [One Dark](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Theme%20-%20One%20Dark). The editor is [Atom](https://atom.io/)

some similar themes:

- [Space Gray](https://github.com/kkga/spacegray)
- [Material Theme](https://github.com/equinusocio/material-theme)

Answer (score 0):

I made a port of Atom's One Dark and One Light UI and syntax theme for Sublime Text 4 and 3.2+, make sure to check it out:
https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Theme%20-%20One
[image: One Theme]